# Faster way of Awking a file from End to Beginning?

Tags: bash, awk, tac

I want to get results starting at the bottom of a file and working my way up to the beginning. I tried using `tac` and pipe that into my `awk` command, but its very slow (15 seconds for an 2GB file).  Compared to searching normally (3 seconds for the same file).  I'm also piping the `awk` command into `tail -n +1 | head -n 50` to stop after 50 results.

Is there a faster way to `tac` a file? or at least start searching from the bottom up?

The big picture is to create a python script that takes arguments (start date, end date, search terms) and use those to search through a date organized log file. Returning 50 results at a time.

I need to read from end to beginning in case a user wants to search in Descending order (newest date to oldest date).

An example command for ascending results ('oldest to newest):
(im using find, because  is a user specified argument, it can potentially reference all files (*.txt))

- Start Date: 2018-03-04T03:45
- End Date: 2018-03-05T16:24
- Search Term: Potato

`find '/home/logs/' -type f -name 'log_file.txt' -exec cat {} \+ 2>&1| LANC=C fgrep 'Potato' | LC_ALL=C IGNORECASE=1 awk -v start="2018-03-04T03:45:00" -v stop="2018-03-05T16:24:59" 'BEGIN{IGNORECASE=1;} {line=$0; xz=" "; for(i=4;i<=NF;i++){xz=xz" "$i};} ($1>=start&&$1<=stop) && (tolower(xz) ~ /Potato/) {print line}' | tail -n +1 | head -n 50`

The `tail -n +1 | head -n 50` is to return the first 50 matches.

This command takes about 3-4 seconds to find results, however if I sub in tac, it takes closer to 20 seconds.

Comment: Am I understanding it correctly that you do something like : `tac <file> | awk 'stuff' | tail -n +1 | head -n 50`? If so, why the `tail -n +1`?

Comment: In order to help you out, we would need to know more about your `awk` script.

Comment: Can you explain what you need this for?  What would you put in the awk body if the `tac` approach would perform well?

Comment: Describe what it is you need to do that makes you want to read the file in reverse order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much faster to open the file, and seek to some amount before the end of the file. Perl is handy here:

```
perl -Mautodie -se '
    $size = -s $file;
    $blocksize = 64000;
    open $fh, "<", $file;
    seek $fh, $size - $blocksize, 0;
    read $fh, $data, $blocksize;
    @lines = split "\n", $data;
    # last 50 lines
    print join "\n", reverse @lines[-51..-1];
' -- -file="filename"
```

We can throw a loop in there so after it reads the last block, it can seek to the end minus 2 blocks and read a block, etc.

But if you want to process the entire gigantic file from bottom to top, you'll have to expect it to take time.

Answer (score 2):

Everything depends a bit on the `awk` code you are having, but some solutions that come to mind are :

- if you print every line:

  ```
  tac <file> | awk '(NR > 50){exit}{do-your-stuff}'
  ```
- if you print only few lines with `awk`

  ```
  tac <file> | awk '(c > 50){exit} 
                    { do-part-of stuff;
                      print foobar; c++;
                      do-remaining part}'
  ```

Both solutions terminate `awk` after the first 50 printed lines. This way you do not have to process the full 2GB file. The termination after 50 printed lines mimicks the `tail -n +1 | head -n 50`

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you got the memory, hash the records and process backwards in `END` section:

```
$ for i in {a..e} ; do echo $i ; done |   
  awk '{ a[NR]=$0 }       # hash to a, NR as key
  END {                   # in the end
      for(i=NR;i>=1;i--)  # process a in descending order
          c++             # process
      print c
}'
5
```

**Update**: I tested above with a 1 GB file (36 M records). It got hashed and counted in 1 minute and sucked about 4.5 GB memory.